# Random pivot not working quick sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am having trouble understanding this `partition` method. Using a random **pivot** doesn't seem to work, it only seems to work if I use one of these as the **pivot**:

- `arr[left]`
- `arr[right - 1]`
- `arr[(left + right) / 2]`

However, I thought any element should work. When I change it to something like `arr[1]` the code stops working... Am I misunderstanding something about the pivot?

Here is the code for the `partition()` method:

```
public static int partition(int arr[], int left, int right) {
    // Pick a pivot point. Can be any element.
    int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2]; 

    while (left <= right) {
        while (arr[left] < pivot) {
            left++;
        }

        while (arr[right] > pivot) {
            right--;
        }

        if (left <= right) {
            swap(arr, left, right);
            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }

    return left;
}
```

And here is a link to the full Quick Sort code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e1c74f2794ecb5b898ab

As a side note, I'm also a bit unsure as why we are returning `left` from the `partition()` method.

Comment: left(you can consider j as left for your case) is returned from left from the partition() method because every elements of A[p..j-1] is less than or equal to every element of A[j..r] when outermost while loop terminate. and please choose variable name wisely.

Answer (score 4):

The pivot in Quicksort should be chosen from the elements of the sub-array being partitioned. Therefore it must be `arr[i]` such that `i` is between `left` and `right`. Choosing `arr[1]` can't work if `left > 1` or `right < 1`.

As for returning `left` - `partition` performs swapping of array elements in the range of `left` to `right` such that after it is done, all the elements from `left` (the original `left` passed to the method) to the `left` returned by the method - 1 are smaller than all the elements from the `left` returned by the method to the original `right` passed to the method. This allows you to make a recursive call to quicksort for each of the two partitions.

The method can return `right` instead, which would require a slight change in the implementation :

Instead of calling

```
    if (left < index - 1) {
        quickSort(arr, left, index - 1);
    }

    if (index < right) {
        quickSort(arr, index, right);
    }
```

after the partition, you'll be calling

```
    if (left < index) {
        quickSort(arr, left, index);
    }

    if (index + 1 < right) {
        quickSort(arr, index + 1, right);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much fixed the title, and that makes sense! So, if you don't mind I have one other question. Why exactly is `left` getting returned?